# Looking for a particular algorithm for numerical integration

Tags: algorithm, numerical-methods, numerical, numerical-integration

Consider the following differential equation
`f(x) = g'(x)`
I have a build a code that spits out values of the function `f(x)` for the variable `x`, where `x` goes from `0` to `very large`.

Now, I'm looking for a scheme that will analyse these values of `f(x)` in order to determine `g(x)`. Does anybody have any suggestions? The main problem is that if I would calculate `g(x) = Integral (f(x) * dx)`, then I'll end up with just a number (i.e. the area under the graph), but I need to know the actual function of `g(x)`.

I've cross-posted this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326854/looking-for-a-particular-algorithm-for-numerical-integration

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to write in LaTeX, I'll try to find the correct edit.

Comment: the equation is really confusing to me (in both questions) so just to clarify the only combination that make sense to me is: `p(t)=q'(t)` ... `q(t)` is derived by `t`, `t` is variable (time), `p(t),q(t)` are functions of `t`, `q(t)` is wanted unknown. so `q(t)=Integral(p(t)*dt)` In what form you have the `p(t)` ? it is polynomial,text representation of equation,it is arbitrary function? Also what constraints (range of `t`) and boundary conditions you have? please clarify because right now is this unanswerable

Comment: @Spektre thanks for your suggestions. I've edited my question to use more conventional notation. But basically what you're writing is correct. The function `g(x)` is the wanted unknown. But the main problem is that if I calculated `g(x) = Integral (f(x) * dx)`, then I'll end up with just a number (i.e. the area under the graph), but I need to know the actual function.

Comment: Oh, and `f(x)` is an arbitrary function.

Comment: in what form is the `f(x)` ?  it is a string, it  is an array representing polynomial ? it is a tree ? .... this is crucial info to solve this

Comment: @Spektre it is an array (i.e. column vector), where each element of the array corresponds to a certain value of `x` and the value of the element corresponds to `f(x)`.

Comment: so `f(x)` is just a table not a function and you want as output function or similar table ?

Comment: added edit1 to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. numerical integration always return just a number

   - if you do not want the number but function instead
   - then **you can not use numerical integration** for this task **directly**
2. Polynomial approach

   - you can use any approximation/interpolation technique to obtain a polynomial representing `f(x)`
   - then integrate as standard polynomial (just change in exponent and multiplication constant)
   - this is not suited for transcendent, periodical or complex shaped functions
   - most common approaches is use of L'Grange or Taylor series
   - for both you need a parser capable of returning value of `f(x)` for any given `x`
3. algebraic integration

   - this is not solvable for any `f(x)` because we do not know how to integrate everything
   - so you would need to program all the rules for integration
   - like per-partes,substitutions,Z or L'Place  transforms
   - and write a solver within string/symbol paradigm
   - that is **huge amount of work**
   - may be there are libs or dlls that can do that
   - from programs like Derive or Matlab ...

**[edit1] As the function `f(x)` is just a table in form**

- `double f[][2]={ x1,f(x1),x2,f(x2),...xn,f(xn) };`
- you can create the same table for `g(x)=Integral(f(x))` at interval `<0,x>`
- so:

  ```
  g(x1)=f(x1)*(x1-0)
  g(x2)=f(x1)*(x1-0)+f(x2)*(x2-x1)
  g(x3)=f(x1)*(x1-0)+f(x2)*(x2-x1)+f(x3)*(x3-x2)
  ...
  ```
- this is just a table so if you want actual function you need to convert this to polynomial via L'Grange or any other interpolation...
- you can also use DFFT and for the function as set of sin-waves